# Is it possible to remove or fix a node from maas after juju bootstrap?

Tags: juju, maas

I don't want to destroy environment of juju.
Is there any way that let me to delete a node in maas with minium change？

Or, if some way can fix the node, that's perfect.

My juju status:

```
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: D1
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-7874253a-a891-11e1-b5bb-0800270f9b01/
    instance-state: unknown
  1:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: D0
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-d1ea1f7e-a8d3-11e1-be27-0800270f9b01/
    instance-state: unknown
  2:
    agent-state: not-started
    dns-name: T2
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-c17f697a-a93a-11e1-b1a3-0800270f9b01/
    instance-state: unknown
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-2
    relations: {}
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 1
        public-address: D0.localdomain
  tomcat7:
    charm: cs:precise/tomcat7-1
    relations:
      cluster:
      - tomcat7
    units:
      tomcat7/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 2
        public-address: null
```

Machine 2 is failed, and reboot for some times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, use `juju destroy-service tomcat7` remove tomcat7 first.

Then, use `juju terminate-machine 2` remove node 2 ok.